# Auto scrolling down a page with jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am trying to get my page to automatically scroll down over 60 seconds.

This is the code I am using:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('html, body').animate({ 
               scrollTop: $(document).height()-$(window).height()}, 
               60000, 
               "linear"
            );
        });
```

However nothing is happening. It is not scrolling at all.

How do I get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Auto scroll to bottom of page with jquery .Try this one. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/LDFd7/)

```
$(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $('html, body').get(0).scrollHeight}, 6000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks that's perfect - is it also possible to pause the scroll through the click event of a button?

Comment: Here with an example.Actually this new example is not mine. http://jsfiddle.net/cMJZ4/1/